# Pyplot to show only the last 60 seconds of a plot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I´m new to matplotlib and python in general.

- I'm on windows running typeperf.exe to basically reads processor information in real time using cli:

`C:\>typeperf "\Procesador(_Total)\% de tiempo de procesador" > C:\Users\hb\Documents\Scripts\log.csv`

- The data structure at the CSV is as follows:

`"07/18/2018 15:50:55.574","3.429826"
"07/18/2018 15:50:56.577","0.307183"
"07/18/2018 15:50:57.589","18.932128"`

- At the same time - same machine - I run a code which basically reads that CSV producing a live plot ( it works! )
- The plot is being drawn with a new line every 1 second.

> **Objective:**  make the graph to show only the last 60 seconds of capture and continue moving forward with the new data in the CSV.

I've read pyplot documentation and tried .clf() and .clear() with no luck. Here's just the portion of code where I´m having a hard time:

```
def animate(i):
    with open(data_in, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
        x, y = [], []

        end_t = time.time() + 60

        while time.time() < end_t:
            for line in range(2):
                next(f_input)

            for row in csv.reader(f_input):
                if row:
                    x.append(datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
                    y.append(float(row[1]))

    ax1.clear()
    plt.title('system\n')
    plt.xlabel('Current Time')
    plt.ylabel('Current HTTP Connections\n')
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    time_format = DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(time_format)
    start += 1

data_out = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

I tried the while loop in an attempt to make the plot read just for that amount of time. It doesn't work.

Would you please point me out to the right path?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like you comparing the actual times, not the times from your csv file.

Comment: If you are confident of the period/sample rate of the data a quick fix might be to just plot the last 60 items in `x` and `y` - `ax1.plot(x[:-60],y[:-60])`.  though you may want to look at the actual timestamps  to determine the  60 second span.  Making `datetime` objects and *doing math* with them would work.

Answer (score 0):

X and Y currently contain all timesteps and values in the .csv file. Instead of plotting X and Y entirely, you could only plot the last 60 values:

```
if len(x) < 60:
    ax1.plot(x,y)
else:
    ax1.plot(x[60:],y[60:])
```

This approach could become cumbersome as the .csv file grows with days and years. In that case refreshing (and archiving) the file every now and then should fix it.

Comment: Another option would be to use [`collections.deque(maxlen=60)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) for `x` and `y`

Comment: Sorry the dealy.  I've succesfully used deque!  Thank you very much !